# Swift: withCheckedContinuation and Dispatch QoSClass

Tags: swift, async-await

I am adapting some old code which was using common completions in order to use the new async/await syntax with Parse SDK. Here is an example, this:

```
static func get(
    className: String,
    id: String,
    _ completion: @escaping (PFObject?) -> Void
) {
    let query = PFQuery(className: className)
    query.getObjectInBackground(withId: id) { object, _ in
        completion(object)
    }
}
```

is becoming this:

```
static func get(
    className: String,
    objectId: String
) async -> PFObject? {
    let query = PFQuery(className: className)
    return await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
        query.getObjectInBackground(withId: objectId) { result, _ in
            continuation.resume(returning: result)
        }
    }
}
```

However, I was also using `DispatchQueue`/`QoS` previously and so the old function actually looked like this:

```
static func get(
    className: String,
    id: String,
    _ completion: @escaping (PFObject?) -> Void
) {
    let query = PFQuery(className: className)
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
        query.getObjectInBackground(withId: id) { object, _ in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(object)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I use this with the async/await syntax? Is it even needed?

Thank you for your help

Comment: It’s not needed. Your old code, calling `getObjectInBackground` on a global queue with particular QoS, is not achieving what you think it is. The `getObjectInBackground` performs a query asynchronously, so the queue from which you submit it is largely irrelevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to execute your async function `get(className:objectId:)` within a Swift Task, using [this Task initialiser](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/init(priority:operation:)-5ltye):

```
func foo(
    className: String,
    objectId: String
) async -> PFObject? {
    await Task(priority: .userInitiated) {
        await get(className: className, objectId: objectId)
    }
    .value
}
```

Note that, when using this Task initialiser you are getting "structured concurrency", which means, that the embedded task in function `foo` inherits the actor context of the calling function.
That is, you can use the result *safely* from whatever thread you called it.

That means also, if the task where function `foo()` is running, gets cancelled, the embedded task will be cancelled as well. Of course, cancellation is cooperatively, which means, you need to stop a running task explicitly. For example, as preferred in your use case, with a `withTaskCancellationHandler`, which calls `cancel()` on your PFQuery object. Or when you have a long running iterating task, you may poll the Task's cancellation status in reasonably steps while your task progresses.

Please also read about "detached" which behave differently regarding cancellation and inheriting the task priority.

As of your question whether it is needed:
I assume, you ask if using specifying a priority is needed:
Short answer: in many use cases it may be more safe to just inherit the priority from whatever thread the function originates.

In your case, I would not explicitly change it: when it is called from a background thread with low priority, your task should inheriting this priority as well. There will be no reason to make it high priority with `userInitiated`. Otherwise, if your function is already called from a user action, it will be inheriting this higher priority as well. I believe, this is what most use cases would require.

Also, when your worker is running in a background thread, as is the case in your code, it really doesn't matter much "how fast you schedule" this task.

So, basically you end up with your async `get` function as defined, use it as is, and all is good. ;)

Comment: @Rob, totally agree. I didn't know that PFQuery is cancellable. But for any "cancellable" (for example a URLSession Task) the `withTaskCancellationHandler` pattern would be the preferred approach. A publisher returned from a URLSession can also be cancelled without polling - just with a different idiomatic pattern.